# How to make vertical scrollbar appear in RMarkdown code chunks (html view)

Tags: html, r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I've found many examples outlining how to add horizontal scrollbars to R Markdown HTML output, including this specific example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578152/make-scrollbar-appear-in-rmarkdown-code-chunks-html-view).  However, none that describe how to add vertical scrollbars. Again borrowing from the linked example, but transposing a wide matrix to a "tall" matrix, I'd like to scroll *vertically* through the matrix in my ioslide presentation.

````
---
title: "Vertical needs"
author: "Hyped"
date: "December 13, 2016"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Where's my vertical scrollbar?

```{r}
x <- matrix(nrow = 40, ncol = 4, data = 1)
x
```
````

The output of the above matrix extends to the bottom edge of the slide and then vanishes. No scrollbar.  I tried modifying the answers given for solving the lack of horizontal scrollbars by modifying the CSS style code added to the .Rmd file (or placed in a custom CSS) **from**

```
<style>
pre code, pre, code {
  white-space: pre !important;
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
  word-break: keep-all !important;
  word-wrap: initial !important;
}
</style>
```

**to** (swapping overflow-x to overflow-y):

```
<style>
pre code, pre, code {
  white-space: pre !important;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  word-break: keep-all !important;
  word-wrap: initial !important;
}
</style>
```

but no luck. Can anyone provide the missing piece of the puzzle?

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be that you did not specify the height of the code chunk. Try this instead:

```
<style>
pre {
  white-space: pre !important;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  height: 50vh !important;
}
</style>
```

(For information about the unit `vh` check [this](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units))

[image]

Comment: This works!  Thanks! However, I had one additional question about the solution.... Other _horizontal scrollbar_ solutions seem to combine the pre tag with the code tag.  However, even adding _echo=TRUE_ to the R-code chunk to see the code text in the output, I don't see any _code_ tags in the HTML source. Instead, I see pre.lang-r which I'm guessing I can set off to separate styles between the code text itself and the output.  Can you offer any comments on this?

Comment: Interestingly I can't find them either. I am not sure if the use of the code tag was removed in recent versions. Anyhow, you can of course use `pre { ... }` and `pre.lang-r { ... }` to set different styles (or `pre:not(lang-r)` and `pre.lang-r { ... }`).

Comment: It does not work on the output table when Kable is used.

Comment: Of course it does not. You would have to change the CSS tag from `pre` to the one that wraps around the kable table.

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto @Martin Schmelzer's solution, I noticed there can be issues if `echo = TRUE`, or if your output is not much large in other parts of the document. To fix this issue just change:

```
height: 50vh !important;
```

to

```
max-height: 50vh !important;
```