# How to make scrollable slides in an ioslides presentation with rmarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, ioslides

I am using RMarkdown to create an ioslide presentation with shiny.
Some of my slides do not actually fit on one page and are truncated.

Since this is a HTML output, I would like to add a scroll bar to make my long slides scrollable.

I have been googling a lot and found a [partial solution to make R code chunks scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135085/how-to-make-vertical-scrollbar-appear-in-rmarkdown-code-chunks-html-view). However I want to make my slides scrollable regardless of the content.

This is a toy Rmd example giving slides not fitting on one page:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "30 October 2018"
output: ioslides_presentation
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Shiny Presentation 

- A very long

- and boring

- list of

- bullet points

- just a

- toy example

- obviously

- not over yet

- almost

- not quite

- finally

- out of frame!
````

I would like to make this slide scrollable since it does not fit on one page.

Edit: I am not sure why this is being heavily downvoted - would appreciate a constructive comment :) In the meantime, I did remove the `css` tag which may have brought people not familiar with rmarkdown.

Comment: Even Though you will self-answer it is still not a good question since you did not provide any information that we could help nor that it will help anyone in the future

Comment: The question is how to add a scrollbar to a slide in an ioslides presentation built with r-markdown. I think this is a clear question with a clear answer (as demonstrated by my answer). The question and its answer would sure have helped me 1 hour ago.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm one of the main authors of the **rmarkdown** package. From my point of view, this is a totally valid and in fact excellent question. I also appreciate that the OP found and shared a solution below. I have always found those who downvote without explanations offensive and irresponsible, and more often than not, [they don't really know what they're doing.](https://yihui.name/en/2018/02/closed-so-question/) I want to challenge those people if they really understand what R Markdown is in the first place. Just because you are an CSS expert doesn't mean you are an `rmarkdown` expert.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Self-answer:

The bit of CSS that will make the slide scrollable (both horizontally and vertically but you just have to remove one line if only vertical scrolling is needed) is:

```
slides > slide {
  overflow-x: auto !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

Note that the slide gets a height from ioslide so there is no need to specify a height (and in fact it seems to introduce visual glitches if you do). Using `auto` instead of `scroll` makes sure a scrollbar only appears when there is a need.

You can either add this CSS directly in the Rmd in between `<style>` tags or put the CSS in a separate file (e.g. `scrollable_slides.css`).

The CSS file can then be added to the Rmd like this (assuming `scrollable_slides.css` is in the same directory as the Rmd):

```
---
title: "..."
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: 'scrollable_slides.css'
runtime: shiny
---
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, but it modifies _all_ slides (with overflow), not _the_ slide. ;) Is there any way to limit this to a single slide?