# How to size a table/str in r presentation?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I can't find a way or a command to size this str() in my slides. Consider that it's 21 attributes and at the moment it shows until the 17th.

```
str(Totallist)
```

I would like to size it as I wish in the slides, but it goes out of borders.

Comment: I recommend using slide animations, first show a chunk of df, by `str(Totallist[, 1:10])` then show `str(Totallist[, 10:20])`

Comment: That's something I thought about but I was trying to find something more specific about sizing

Comment: How about making it scrollable as described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53064652/2554330