# Compact table in html document rmarkdown with kableExtra?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra, knitrbootstrap

I'm trying to make a ['compact'](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#small-table) table in an RMarkdown

I've tried a few things, mostly variations on [setting a custom css class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38579910) and [providing the custom css class to a code chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38168021/5783745)

I've tried a lot of variations, all of which I can see flow through to the source code (accessed via knitting the html document, opening in chrome, and <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> to view source and inspecting the source)

However, I can't work out what's necessary to simply make rows thinner (I believe that's simply reducing cell padding) in a `kableExtra` table

#### What I've tried so far

Here's one variation of what I've tried, but the rows are not compact as hoped (they are the standard height)

[image]

Which is done with:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr); library(kableExtra)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
```

<style>
pre code, pre, code {
    padding: 200 !important;
}
</style>

```{r}
iris %>% 
  kable %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(4:5, bold = T) %>%
  row_spec(3:5, bold = T, color = "white", background = "#D7261E")
```
````

but note that the custom css is not taking effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to override the Bootstrap CSS, decreasing value of `padding` property (default value is `8px`):

```
<style>
.table>tbody>tr>td{
  padding: 1px;
}
</style>
```

As you pointed out, inspecting the source will lead you to the values above:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something similar within `row_spec(1:nrow(iris), extra_css = "..")`

Comment: Radovan's solution worked for me, but I will be sure to try this next time

Answer (score 1):

To make the kable rows smaller in a knit to HTML, you can use *bootstrap_options = c("condensed")* in your kable_styling:

```
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("condensed"))
```

See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html

The pdf variant for it:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/kableExtra.pdf